# How do I tokenize a text data into words and sentences without getting a type error

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

My end goal is to use NER models to identify custom entities. Before doing this, I am tokenizing the text data into words and sentences. I have a folder of text files(.txt) that I opened and read into Jupyter using the os library. After reading the text file, whenever I try to tokenize the text files, I get a type error. Could please advise on what I am doing wrong? My code is below, Thanks.

```
import os
outfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
path = "C:/Users/okeke/Documents/Work flow/IT Text analytics Project/Extract/Dubuque_text-nlp"
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    outfile.write(str(os.stat(path + "/" + file).st_size) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

This code runs fine, whenever I run the outfile, I get this below

```
outfile
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='result.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Next, tokenization.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
sent_tokens = sent_tokenize(outfile)
print(outfile)

word_tokens = word_tokenize(outfile)
print(outfile
```

But then I get an error after the running the code above. Check for error below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-62f66183895a> in <module>
      1 from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
----> 2 sent_tokens = sent_tokenize(outfile)
      3 print(outfile)
      4 
      5 #word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in sent_tokenize(text, language)
     93     """
     94     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
---> 95     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     96 
     97 # Standard word tokenizer.
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You probably need to re-open outfile in read mode then call `sent_tokens = sent_tokenize(outfile.read())`

Comment: I am getting an error . `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-52349d8fcb9c> in <module>
      1 from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
----> 2 sent_tokens = sent_tokenize(outfile.read())
      3 print(outfile)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: Close the file then re-open. `outfile.close()` then `with open('results.txt') as outfile:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

You are trying to process the file object instead of the text in the file. After you create the text file, re-open it and read the entire file before tokenizing.

Try this code:

```
import os
outfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
path = "C:/Users/okeke/Documents/Work flow/IT Text analytics Project/Extract/Dubuque_text-nlp"
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    with open(path + "/" + file) as f:
       outfile.write(f.read() + '\n')
       #outfile.write(str(os.stat(path + "/" + file).st_size) + '\n')

outfile.close()  # done writing


from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
with open('result.txt') as outfile:  # open for read
   alltext = outfile.read()  # read entire file
   print(alltext)

   sent_tokens = sent_tokenize(alltext)  # process file text. tokenize sentences   
   word_tokens = word_tokenize(alltext)  # process file text. tokenize words
```

Comment: Hi Mike thank you for your assistance so far. The code worked but it is printing out the byte size of each text file in the directory not the contents of the file. After running this code, i got the byte size `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
with open('result.txt') as outfile:  # open for read
    alltext = outfile.read()  # read entire file
print(alltext)` .Here is the result I got from the code above:  2004
2062
1952
644

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you're writing files sizes to `result.txt`: `outfile.write(str(os.stat(path + "/" + file).st_size) + '\n')`  What is the goal of that loop?

Comment: The goal is to read all the contents of the text files in the directory, then tokenize it. After tokenizing and cleaning the text data, I will construct a NER model.